# active c++ mode in a block of region

Tags: emacs

Is it possible to activate C++ mode or any other mode in a block of region? I think this would be convenient when taking notes or integrating C++ with literate style coding.

Comment: Useful reading: [multiple modes in a buffer](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes); for taking notes, [org mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OrgMode) has this and much more

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Major Modes aren't supported by Emacs (yet). But there are hacks to make it work

- [EmacsWiki-MultiModes](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes)
- MMM at [GitHub](https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following emacs wikis:

- [Mmm Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MmmMode)
- [Multiple Modes](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes)